# Rows not being added to data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

So, I've been trying to do a simulation study about a SIR-model.

I have the following code (Tryed to clean it up):

```
# Initial parameters
N <- 1E6            # Total population
I <- 1              # Number of Infectious at time 0
S <- N-1            # Number of Susceptibles at time 0
R <- 0             # Number of Recovered at time 0

# Vector to store observations in
Df1 <- data.frame("final_size" = as.numeric(), "peak_size" = as.numeric())

# Setting a seed for reproducibility 
set.seed(1996)
n_sim <- 100

# Setting different values for R0, the basic reproduction number
R0 <- seq(0.5,2.5, 1)

for(values in R0){
  if(values == 0.5){
    # Transmission parameters
    R0 <- values    # Basic Reproduction number
    nu <- 1/6             # Recovery rate (in days) 
    b <- nu*R0/N        # Infection rate (in days)
    for(sim in n_sim){
      temp <- NULL
      # Binomial model
      #----------------
      # Initial states
      Sold = S          # Number of Susceptibles at time t=0
      Iold = I          # Number of Infectious at time t=0
      Rold = R          # Number of Recovered at time t=0
      # Output vectors
      Svec =Sold; Ivec = Iold; Rvec = Rold
      stop = FALSE
      # Loop - continue until stop=TRUE
      while (!stop){        
        Ih = rbinom(1,Sold,(1-exp(-b*Iold)))
        Rh = rbinom(1,Iold,(1-exp(-nu)))
        Rh = nu*Iold
        Sold = Sold-Ih
        Iold = Iold+Ih-Rh
        Rold = Rold+Rh
        Svec = c(Svec,Sold)
        Ivec = c(Ivec,Iold)
        Rvec = c(Rvec,Rold)
        if (Iold<=2e-5){stop=T}
      }
      peak_size_df <- max(Ivec)
      final_size_df <- Rvec[length(Rvec)]/N
      temp <- rbind(temp, c(final_size_df, peak_size_df))
      colnames(temp) <- c("final_size", "peak_size")
      Df1 <- rbind(Df1, temp)
    }
  }
}
```

I'm looking to store data in Df1. However, at the end of the loop, only 1 loop has been stored, I assume the last loop. Which I don't really properly understand. I've recoded it a few times and in those cases I ended up with 99 NA rows for final size and peak size. In this version, I only end up with 1 row (with values however). I plan on expanding the loop for different values of R0 as seen in the R0 seq. Due to it not working for the first value, I haven't expanded it yet.
Any suggestions? Improvements?

After comments from Gregory and Cath, the following adjustments:

```
# Setting a seed for reproducibility 
#set.seed(1996)
n_sim <- 100


# Initial parameters
N <- 1E6            # Total population
I <- 1              # Number of Infectious at time 0
S <- N-1            # Number of Susceptibles at time 0
R <- 0            # Number of Recovered at time 0


# Vector to store observations in
Df1 <- data.frame("final_size" = rep(NA, n_sim), "peak_size" = rep(NA, n_sim))
Df2 <- NULL
Df3 <- NULL


# Setting different values for R0, the basic reproduction number
R0 <- seq(0.5,2.5, 1)



#plot(Svec, type = "l", ylim = c(0, 1000000), col = "red")
#lines(Rvec, type = "l", col = "blue")
#lines(Ivec, type = "l")
#max(Ivec)

for(values in R0){
  if(values == 0.5){
    # Transmission parameters
    R0_value <- values    # Basic Reproduction number
    nu <- 1/6             # Recovery rate (in days) 
    b <- nu*R0_value/N      # Infection rate (in days)
    for(sim in n_sim){
      # Binomial model
      #----------------
      # Initial states
      Sold = S          # Number of Susceptibles at time t=0
      Iold = I          # Number of Infectious at time t=0
      Rold = R          # Number of Recovered at time t=0
      # Output vectors
      Svec =Sold; Ivec = Iold; Rvec = Rold
      stop = FALSE
      # Loop - continue until stop=TRUE
      while (!stop){        
        Ih = rbinom(1,Sold,(1-exp(-b*Iold)))
        Rh = rbinom(1,Iold,(1-exp(-nu)))
        Rh = nu*Iold
        Sold = Sold-Ih
        Iold = Iold+Ih-Rh
        Rold = Rold+Rh
        Svec = c(Svec,Sold)
        Ivec = c(Ivec,Iold)
        Rvec = c(Rvec,Rold)
        if (Iold<=2e-5){stop=T}
      }
      peak_size_df <- max(Ivec)
      final_size_df <- Rvec[length(Rvec)]/N
      Df1[sim, "final_size"] <- final_size_df
      Df1[sim, "peak_size"] <- peak_size_df
    }
  }
}
```

Which gives me 99 rows with NA and row 100 the last simulation with values.
Any idea what is causing the NA's?

Comment: Using `rbind` at every step of a loop is the worst way to add values to a data frame. It is the second circle of R Hell in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). It's much better to initialize your data frame to the correct length with, say, all `NA` values and then replace the `NA`s with actual values as needed.

Comment: it seems `temp` is put back to NULL at each step of your loop (and besides, same comment as Gregor's ;-) )

Comment: Not sure what `temp <- rbind(temp, c(final_size_df, peak_size_df))` is doing - why use `rbind` here? As Cath says, `temp` is NULL going into that line.

Comment: Would it be more like:
Df1 <- data.frame("final_size" = rep(NA, n.sim), "peak_size" = rep(NA, n.sim))
And then:
Df1[sim, "final_size"] <- final_size_df
Df1[sim, "peak_size"] <- peak_size_df

Comment: Also, though perhaps not technically wrong, I find your using `R0` as the looping bounds (`R0 <- seq(0.5,2.5, 1)` then `for(values in R0){...`, but then change `R0 inside the loop `R0 <- values`) to be very confusing.

Comment: @GregorThomas, True, adjusted it to something more clear now.

Comment: `for (value in 1:n_sim){...` ;-)  (here, sim takes only value n_sim = 100, hence the 100th row is the only one filled)

Comment: @Cath and Gregor
Thank you both. That did the job Cat :-). Also thanks for pointing out about the loop-ethics, always good to learn about it...